# Take input from text file then INSERT and UPDATE database table using shell script

Tags: shell-script, mysql

I have a `demo.txt` file which contains ip. This text file updates daily.
I have created a table which stores `id, ip, date`.
I want to `INSERT` and `UPDATE` ip from text file into DATABASE table with some conditions.

1. If duplicate ip is found in text file, then UPDATE `DATE` column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to that specific record.
2. If new ip is found, then INSERT record into TABLE.

demo.txt file looks like :

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
1.1.1.1
```

I have tried these :

```
 CREATE TABLE `demo` (
  `id` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(6) ON UPDATE current_timestamp(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**BASH SCRIPT :**

```
#!/bin/bash
inputfile="demo.txt"
cat $inputfile | while read ip ; do
     echo "INSERT INTO demo (ip) VALUES ('$ip');"
        done | mysql -u root -proot demo;
```

Above script inserts ip into table but do not update table. It's update only if new record is found.

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: records are one below the other.

Comment: Have a look at [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/) to avoid the temporary table (and possibly also fix your problem, because now you are doing it in a different way).

Comment: Can you brief me exactly what should I do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your `demo.txt` file. You show us something you call "input file" but that only has one IP per line so it can't be what you are reading since you seem to be expecting two variables, `records` and `status`.

Comment: Please review question and if possible help me out.

Comment: @dirtkt it works for me. Thank u all.